# How to get specific data from JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have json file like this:

```
    [
      {"category":"food","id":"07","name":"hey"},
      {"category":"not","id":"06","name":"hey1"},
      {"category":"food","id":"05","name":"hey2"},
      {"category":"not","id":"04","name":"hey3"}
    ]
```

How to get all "names" that have "category":"food"?
I am trying like this, but it doesnt work correctly.

```
    $.getJSON( "test.json", function( data ) {
      var items = [];
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
      if (val.category = "food"){
        items.push( "<li>" + val.name + "</li>" );
      }
    });

    $( "<ul/>", {
      "class": "my-new-list",
      html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "div" );
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use the `===` operator (you can use `==` instead but it's considered better practice to use `===` ). You're code as written will include every element in the object because `if (val.category = "food" )` will always evaluate to true and it will actually change the `category` value.

Fix below.

```
if (val.category === "food"){
        items.push( "<li>" + val.name + "</li>" );
}
```